# separation of variables in differential euqtions and compact self-adjoint operators

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

For some partial differential equations in physics, people may separate the variables and get some eigenfunctions. And then for any solutions for that equation, people often suppose them to be a Fourier series of those eigenfunctions. But why is it right? I think it is a little too wayward ... I know that there is some relations between this procedure and the theory of compact self-adjoint operators, but don't know the details ...

Comment: What is your background, and what do you already know about the problem? You will be more likely to attract answers if you read mathoverflow.net/howtoask and implement some of the strategies listed there. As the question stands, it is likely to be closed (but don't panic, if the question is improved, it can be reopened).

Comment: I believe that separation of variables is usually completely rigorous if done right. On the other hand, I am voting to close this question.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will improve it to meet the stands.

Comment: That's much better...

Comment: I think this question is more suitable to mathexchange. In any case, separation of variables can be justified by the fact that eigenfunctions of a self-adjoint operator form an orthonormal basis for the appropriate Hilbert space.

Comment: Thank you. But what is mathexchange? Seems like it is a French site?

Comment: @timur: how so?

Comment: @braill: @timur means math.stackexchange.com I actually don't agree, I think this question is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: The rigorous analysis of the "eigenfunction expansion" for self-adjoint operators on a Hilbert space is provided by the Spectral Theorem.  You might look at Akhiezer and Glazman, Theory of Linear Operators in Hilbert Space, Appendix II: Differential Operators, for a thorough treatment of these questions.
